# Javascript: Get attribute of closest neighbour element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a static html file which does not get filled from a database. It basically looks like this:

```
<figure>
 <figcaption>INSERT SRC ATTRIBUTE OF AUDIO HERE</figcaption>
 <audio controls src="files_a.m4a"></audio>
</figure>

<figure>
 <figcaption>INSERT SRC ATTRIBUTE OF AUDIO HERE</figcaption>
 <audio controls src="files_b.m4a"></audio>
</figure>

<figure>
 <figcaption>INSERT SRC ATTRIBUTE OF AUDIO HERE</figcaption>
 <audio controls src="files_c.m4a"></audio>
</figure>
```

I would like to display the SRC-Attribute of `<audio>` at `<figcaption>` .

I can not work with different IDs here because this static code is always the same, except that the src-attribute of `<audio>` gets changed.

So, I would like to ask if there is any option to read the src-attribute from `<audio>` at `<figcaption>`? Is there any option to read the src attribute from a neighbour element although it has no unique ID?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the figure elements, grab the src text from the `audio` elements, and the apply it to the `figcaption` `textContent`.

```js
const figures = document.querySelectorAll('figure');

figures.forEach(figure => {
  const { src } = figure.querySelector('audio');
  const caption = figure.querySelector('figcaption').textContent = src;
});
```

```html
<figure>
 <figcaption>INSERT SRC ATTRIBUTE OF AUDIO HERE</figcaption>
 <audio controls src="files_a.m4a"></audio>
</figure>

<figure>
 <figcaption>INSERT SRC ATTRIBUTE OF AUDIO HERE</figcaption>
 <audio controls src="files_b.m4a"></audio>
</figure>

<figure>
 <figcaption>INSERT SRC ATTRIBUTE OF AUDIO HERE</figcaption>
 <audio controls src="files_c.m4a"></audio>
</figure>
```